# C# Error while getting data from a web page

Tags: c#

Receiving this error: System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.' Yet I can still access the data in a web browser.

`WebClient client = new WebClient();
            String downloadedString = client.DownloadString("https://api.gdax.com/products/LTC-USD/book/");`

Comment: 400 means there was something wrong with the request you sent at least according to the server. Does this request work for other sites?

Comment: That request returns a JSON object. Perhaps share what you would like to do with that string to provide context for people to provide a better answer.

Comment: @MukeshIngham the request does work for other sites however the first api is more accurate, for example: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/litecoin/

Comment: @Luke Was trying to deserialize the JSON object and started getting this error. Attempted to see if I could even get the string value with the code listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong. It must  be with file name at the end. See below:

```
https://api.gdax.com/products/LTC-USD/book/index.html or default.aspx
```

Comment: Did not work. Also this api works and does not need .html after, https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/litecoin/